# awk: count number of occurrences of a particular pattern between two patterns

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following content:

```
pattern1  
pattern2  
pattern3  
blah  
blah  
pattern3  
pattern3  
blah  
pattern3  
pattern1  
pattern2  
blah  
pattern3  
pattern1  
pattern2  
blah  
pattern3  
blah  
pattern3
```

I would like to print `pattern1, pattern2, pattern3`, and the total number of occurrences for `pattern3` within each set of `pattern1` and `pattern2`.  In other words, the desired result:

```
pattern1  
pattern2  
pattern3: 4  
pattern1  
pattern2  
pattern3: 1  
pattern1  
pattern2  
pattern3: 2
```

How can the above be achieved through `awk`?

Comment: but the last `pattern 3` is not enclosed with `pattern 1 pattern 2`

Comment: For now, I would be happy to ignore the last pattern3:

Comment: you mean not to show the last `pattern3: 2` ?

Comment: Correct. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "pattern", which do you mean - regexp or string? It makes a difference to the appropriate solution. Some solutions you've got so far search for one or the other or both in the same script! Never use the word "pattern" in this context as it's ambiguous/meaningless and leads to buggy implementations. Also pattern 1 is ALWAYS paired with pattern2 so why test for both?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `pattern2` line is always going after `pattern1` line (considering that `pattern 3` lines which aren't enclosed with `pattern 1 pattern 2` lines on both sides should be ignored):

```
awk '/pattern2/{ if(p){ print "pattern3: "a[p] } p++; print "pattern1" ORS $0 }
     /pattern3/ && p{a[p]++}' file
```

The output:

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 4
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 1
pattern1
pattern2
```

---

- `/pattern2/` - performs action on each encountering line matching `pattern2` (right after `pattern1`)

  -- `p++;` - incrementing flag `p` (points to the current `pattern 1 pattern 2` subset)
- `/pattern3/ && p` - performs action on each encountering line matching `pattern3` with "active" flag `p`

  -- `a[p]++` - counting `pattern3` lines for the current subset

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check for both pattern1 and pattern2...

```
$ awk 'function pr()   {if(c) print p3":",c}
           /^pattern1/ {p1=$0; pr(); s=c=0; next}
     p1 && /^pattern2/ {print p1 ORS $0; s=1; next}
      s && /^pattern3/ {c++; p3=$0; next}
     END               {pr()}' file

pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 4
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 1
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear so I'm making several assumptions here but @RomanPerekherst asked me to post a solution so here goes given one possible interpretation of your requirements:

Assuming you want to do regexp comparisons on all "pattern"s and want to print the lines from your input that matched "pattern1" and "pattern2", and exactly the string "pattern3":

```
$ cat tst.awk
prev~/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ { prt(); hdr=prev ORS $0 }
/pattern3/ { cnt++ }
{ prev=$0 }
END { prt() }
function prt() { if (hdr!="") print hdr ORS "pattern3:", cnt+0; cnt=0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 4
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 1
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3: 2
```

The above also assumes that though you haven't shown it in your example, pattern2 can occur separately from pattern1 in your input and if either occurs on it's own it should be ignored. If that's not true and they ALWAYS occur together then of course the solution can be simpler as you then don't need to test for both.

Answer (score 1):

try: Providing 2 solutions here.

**1st Solution:** In case you don't want to check like pattern1 and pattern2 both are present or not and simply want to count the string pattern3's count in each batch of pattern1 to next occurrence of pattern1, then following may help you.

```
awk '/^pattern2/{
                        print;
                        next
                }
     /^pattern3/{
                        y++;
                        next
                }
     /^pattern1/ && A{
                        print "pattern3: "y;
                        y=A=""
                     }
     /^pattern1/{
                        print;
                        A++;
                }
     END{
                if(A){
                        print "pattern3: "y;
                     }
        }
    '    Input_file
```

**2nd solution:** When you bother to check if pattern1 is present and then pattern2 should be there in each occurrence of pattern1 to next occurrence of pattern1, then following may help you.

```
awk '/^pattern2/ && A{
                        VAL=VAL ORS $0;
                        B++;
                        next
                     }
     /^pattern3/ && B{
                        y++;
                        next
                     }
     /^pattern1/ && A && B{
                                print VAL ORS "pattern3: ",y=y?y:0;
                                y=A=B=VAL=""
                          }
     /^pattern1/{
                        VAL=$0;
                        A++;
                }
     END{
                if(A && B){
                        print VAL ORS "pattern3: ",y=y?y:0;
                     }
        }
    '  Input_file
```

Will add explanations too shortly.

**EDIT1:** Adding explanation of solution 1st here too.

```
awk '/^pattern2/{                             ##### Checking if current line which starts from pattern2.
                        print;                ##### Then print that line.
                        next                  ##### mentioning next keyword of awk will skip all further statements on this/current line reading and will take the awk's cursor to next line then.
                }
     /^pattern3/{                             ##### Checking if current line which starts from pattern3.
                        y++;                  ##### Incrementing a variable with value 1 each time cursor comes here, so count the values of pattern3 string.
                        next                  ##### next keyword will skip all the further statements for the current line and will take the cursor of awk to next line.
                }
     /^pattern1/ && A{                        ##### Checking if current line which starts from string pattern1 and NOT having NULL value of variable named A.
                        print "pattern3: "y;  ##### If above condition is TRUE then print the pattern3 string and variable y's value, which is the count of pattern3 string.
                        y=A=""                ##### Nullifying the values of y and A here.
                     }
     /^pattern1/{                             ##### Checking if current line starts from string pattern1 here.
                        print;                ##### printing the line.
                        A++;                  ##### Incrementing the value of variable named A with 1, each time it comes in this section.
                }
     END{                                     ##### starting the END block of awk code here.
                if(A){                        ##### Checking if variable A's value is present OR NOT NULL here.
                        print "pattern3: "y;  ##### Then print the string pattern3 and y's value.
                     }
        }
    '    Input_file                           ##### Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

**EDIT2:** Adding 2nd solution's explanation here too now.

```
awk '/^pattern2/ && A{                                                ##### Checking if current line starts from string pattern2 and value of variable A is NOT NULL. If both conditions are TRUE then go to following section.
                        VAL=VAL ORS $0;                               ##### Creating a variable named VAL, whose value will be current line's value.
                        B++;                                          ##### Creating a variable named B, whose value will get incremented each time cursor comes in this section.
                        next                                          ##### next keyword of awk will skip all the further statements for the current line which awk is reading.
                     }
     /^pattern3/ && B{                                                ##### Checking if current line starts from string pattern3 and value of variable B is NOT NULL, if yes then enter into the following code section of it, same like if condition.
                        y++;                                          ##### Incrementing the variable named y's value with 1 each time cursor enters into this section, to count the pattern3's value.
                        next                                          ##### next keyword of awk will skip all the further statements for the current line which awk is reading.
                     }
     /^pattern1/ && A && B{                                           ##### Checking if current line starts from pattern1 and value of variables A and B is NOT NULL. If yes, then perform following section.
                                print VAL ORS "pattern3: ",y=y?y:0;   ##### printing the value of variable VAL then ORS(output record separator, whose default value is a new line), string pattern3 with variable y's value. Here I am checking if variable y is having value then simply print it else print 0 on it's place.
                                y=A=B=VAL=""                          ##### Nullifying the values of variables y,A,B,VAL here.
                          }
     /^pattern1/{                                                     ##### Checking if current line starts from sting pattern1, then enter into following section of code.
                        VAL=$0;                                       ##### Assigning the value of variable named VAL to current line.
                        A++;                                          ##### Incrementing the value of variable named A to 1, each time it cursor comes into this section.
                } 
     END{                                                             ##### Mentioning END section of awk code here.
                if(A && B){                                           ##### Checking if variables A and B both are NOT NULL.
                        print VAL ORS "pattern3: ",y=y?y:0;           ##### Then printing the value of variable VAL, ORS then string pattern3 and value of y(if y is having values then y else 0 on it's place).
                     }
        }
    '  Input_file                                                     ##### mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your goal by adding some if-statements in the `awk` command.
Refer followed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=0}                                                                                       
{
  if ($1 == "pattern1" || $1 == "pattern2" )
  { 
    if (n != 0)
    {
      printf "pattern3:%d\n",n;
      n=0;
    }
    print $1
  }
  if ($1 == "pattern3") n++
}
END{
  if (n != 0)
  {
    printf "pattern3:%d\n",n;
  }
}' file
```